# Display text as html markup

Tags: html

I have a problem which is probably trivially easy but I can't seem to get it working. Using [this](http://weblogs.asp.net/farazshahkhan/regex-to-find-url-within-text-and-make-them-as-link) post, I do a search using Regex in a text string to convert any links into html markup, but when it comes to display on the page it just displays like this:

this is link

```
<a href='http://www.google.com'>http://www.google.com</a>
```

In the view I have:

```
<p>@news.Body</p>
```

edit: great my question is now displaying how I want.  So now to the actual question, how do I get the page displaying an actual link instead of the code when displayed to the user.

Comment: This kind of question belongs to [meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/)

Comment: thanks have edited OP as to what I'm trying to actually accomplish

Comment: You need another property or method that returns a modified string (where you would use the Regex) and you set `<p>@news.AlteredBody</p>` in the view.

Comment: @news.Body is already displaying the altered string, but it still doesn't show as a link.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use `` around your variable (`e.g.`)
2. Use "{}" icon in toolbar to insert `code`
3. Indent your code by one empty line, 4 spaces and leading empty line

E.g.:

```
Like this
```

*You can edit this answer to see raw output*